# pipenv-2018.11.26 can't be installed using pip due to setuptools although it does exist

Tags: pip, setuptools, pipenv

I have been trying to install pipenv-2018.11.26 (`sudo pip3 install pipenv-2018.11.26.tar.gz`), while processing it output is

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

I do have setuptools (`setuptools<=40.6.2`). I tried other versions of setuptools (`41.2.0`,`39.1.0`) to no avail. The above error doesn't show which version of setuptools satisfies pipenv.

I can't use conda, I am using ubuntu server remotely, and install each package manually.

Hope to get it resolved!

Comment: What is the output of `sudo pip3 show setuptools` ?

Answer (score 0):

This version of pipenv requires setuptools>=36.2.1.
Try with this wheel: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/86/095d2f7829badc207c893dd4ac767e871f6cd547145df797ea26baea4e2e/setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: it's actually 41.2.0, not 36.2.1

Comment: That's the setuptools wheel pipenv downloads during installation if you got pipenv from pypi(https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/e9/01822318551caa0d62a181ba3b10f0f3757bb1e270da97165bd52db92776/pipenv-2018.11.26.tar.gz). But I try this installation on Ubuntu WSL. Can you show your pipenv log from ~./pip/pip.log?

Comment: sorry, didn't get what mean